# Prove that if $T \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ and $X$ is reflexive, then $T$ is weakly compact

Tags: functional-analysis

Let be $X,Y$ Banach spaces and we denote $B_X, B_Y$ the respective closed balls. Let be
\begin{equation*} 
\mathcal{L}(X,Y) = \{T: X \rightarrow Y : \text{linear and continuous in norm}\}
\end{equation*}
We say $T\in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ is compact if the clausure of $T(B_X)$ is compact (in norm) in $Y$. We say $T$ is weakly compact if the clausure of $T(B_X)$ is weakly compact in $Y$. I have to prove that if $T\in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ and $X$ is a reflexive space, then $T$ is weakly compact. I have just proved that in this hypothesis for all bounded sequence $x_n \in X$, there exists a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that $T(x_{n_k})$ is weakly convergent in $Y$.
¿Could anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe Banach Alaoglu can help?

Comment: But Banach - Alouglu theorem is for weak star topology   no?

Comment: And in a reflexive space...

Comment: So, I have that $B_X$ is weakly compact and $T(B_X)$ is weakly compact ( T is continuous) and I use the fact i have proved.